# CodedUI prints "pipe" instead of "slash"

Tags: vb.net, coded-ui-tests, slash

I have a problem with using `Keyboard.SendKeys` in CodedUI tests during entering date. I have simple html page with textbox (input[type='text']) and I'm trying to enter date in format (M/dd/yyyy) into it by following command (I am using VB.NET):

```
    Mouse.Click(htmledit)
    Keyboard.SendKeys("^A") ' Sending keys to select all and delete hence clear content of the textbox
    Keyboard.SendKeys("{DEL}")
    Keyboard.SendKeys("10/10/2014")
```

In my machine, it works just quick and perfect.

But, today's morning I tried to run test on the another machine and I noticed that it types pipe (vertical bar) instead of each slash! So, what I got is: `10|10|2014`..

I was very surprised and tried another symbols and they work just as fine as on the my machine.

By googling this problem I have nothing. Does anyone know how to fix it? And I am very curious why it happens? `Keyboard.SendKeys` depends on what?

Thank you.

Comment: In which locale and with which keyboard? From MSDN: _If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided._ :| You may try to escape as {/} but well...I'm not sure it's valid or not.

Comment: Wow, I don't about "unpredictable results"... No, `{/}` doesn't work either. The machine's location where it happens is "United States", and keyboard is ENG. I also connected to it via RDP (if it helps).